# Settings up URL rewrite on sub domain

Tags: .htaccess

**The problem:**

I've got a series of Domains linked to my server, currently my wedding site runs from a folder called /wedding. In my cPanel i've set the default destination to this folder, and within it are all my files, index.html, location.html and so on..

Now my problem so far is that nothing i've tried seems to be letting me remove the .html from the ends of URLs.

**Currently im trying:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^gallery$ ./wedding/gallery.html  
</IfModule>
```

I'll be honest, i've got no idea what im doing. Some help would be really appreciated. I just want clean URLs

Comment: So if you try to go to `http://your.domain.com/gallery`, what happens? Nothing? A 404 error?

Comment: Multiple Choices

The document name you requested (/index) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
Available documents:

/index.html (common basename)
Please consider informing the owner of the referring page about the broken link.

Comment: That output is from mod_spelling, try adding a `CheckSpelling Off` to turn off that module.

Comment: Ok ill give it a go and let you know

Comment: And if you go to `http://your.domain.com/wedding/gallery.html` it's fine?

Comment: Yeh, you can see it here www.winter-wedding.me.uk , if you click gallery from the homepage, youll see page not found. If you add .html it works fine :s

Comment: Make sure your htaccess file is in your document root, and make sure mod_rewrite is loaded

Comment: Itscurrently in my /wedding directory, i assume this is correct, as the domain start folder is here.

Comment: By the way how so i check if mod rewrite is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

> Itscurrently in my /wedding directory, i assume this is correct, as the domain start folder is here.

If it's in your `wedding` directory, the htaccess file will never get accessed if you go to `http://your.domain.com/gallery` (no /wedding/ in the URI path). You need to put the htaccess file, or at least the rules from the file) in your document root.

Comment: I think it was something to do with the other rubbish put in the .htaccess from the template file i used.